# Word Guessing Game

Tags: java, beginner, strings, homework

I'm trying to learn Java (albeit rather slowly). I'm in a computer science class at my highschool and I've written this little bit of code for a project. Basically it is a word guessing game where if you get a letter correct it reveals it. If you get a letter correct in the wrong spot it marks it with a +, and if the letter is not present at all it marks it with a *.

I'm wondering if anyone can give me feedback as to how I can improve this code.

Here is the assignment page if I didn't do an adequate job of explaining what the goal was:

[image]

```
public class main {
    private int length;
    private String word;
    private String result;
    private String buffer;
    public main(String aword) {

        result = "";
        word = aword;
        length = word.length();
        buffer = "";

    }
    public String guess(String aguess) {
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            buffer = aguess.substring(i, i+1);
            if(word.indexOf(buffer) == i)
                result = result + buffer;
            else if ((word.indexOf(buffer) != -1))
                result = result + "+";
            if ((word.indexOf(buffer) == -1)) 
                result = result + "*";
        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you call your class `HiddenWord` as required in the problem statement?

Comment: I made the class from memory then found the question once I was finished to post here. I actually had to retype this because the original was done on a lab computer (I had the correct class name in the version I turned in)

Comment: There's a possible *bug in the question*: Why will guessing `AAAAA` for `HARPS` result in 4 `+`, since I have guessed the only `A` correctly? Another example, given a guess `AAB` for the word `ABA`, I will expect the output to be `A++`, since the `B` and the *second* `A` are not in the right order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was already brought out in the comment part of the requirement was to name your class `HiddenWord`. Granted you are in school and it is probably not going to be used much outside of your class room it is good practice to stick with the requirements...ESPECIALLY if you want to make this a career!

Enough on that though. What I typically do with people who are new to a language is mention the wonders of unit testing, and writing tests and so forth. Seeing as I deleted Netbeans, and IntelliJ is taking a year to download I guess I'm forced to use Notepadd++ and hope that my syntax is close enough.

**What is Unit testing, and why should you care?**

Unit testing is a fast and reliable way (albeit tricky) to verify functionality of your code. The code is typically separated from production code so you don't have to include it in the finished product. There are different types of unit testing and different ways to go about doing the same thing. They all have the same goal in mind. "Make sure your code works as expected" Now as for why you should care about it the list could go on for some time. Some practical reasons are that it is a fast way to get feedback if you programmed something correctly (or incorrectly). It is a form of documentation (for others who may review your code).

There are an exhaustive list of books, blogs, and videos on the internet about it, so I'll just stick with the issue at hand. I'm going to go out on a limb and assume that you verified the results with your eyes by typing in input. and while this is all well in good, it is comparatively slow. Consider the following TestNG test (there are also other test frameworks available such as JUnit, but I am unfamiliar with them)

Just so you know I'll be using TestNG as my testframework, and this is what the entire test class looks like (without the tests)

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.testng.Assert.*;

/**
 * Created by Robert on 5/10/2015.
 */
public class HiddenWordTest {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

    }

    @Test
    public void testGetHint() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Now comes the hard/fun part. Writing a test that is simple to pass, but also is a baby step to completing your goal. Here is a easy one. The hard part is only write enough code to make this test pass, and no more!

```
@Test
public void testWhenLetterIsFoundGetHintReturnsLetter() throws Exception {
    HiddenWord puzzle = new HiddenWord("A");
    String hint = puzzle.getHint("A");

    assertEquals("A", hint);
}
```

that test takes 0.387 seconds to run. What does it do? Well I create a new instance of HiddenWord with the hidden word being simply "A". I then get the hint for a letter "A". well.. according to your specifications that should return simply A. Next test. Wrong letter, and the secret word does not contain the specified character at all.

```
@Test
public void testWhenLetterIsNotFoundHintReturnsStar() {
    HiddenWord puzzle = new HiddenWord("A");
    String hint = puzzle.getHint("B");

    assertEquals(hint, "*");
}
```

So Those 2 tests take 0.35 seconds to run.. (Told you same time). The next test is a little harder, but is essentially the last step.

```
@Test
public void testWhenLetterIsFoundInWrongPlaceHintReturnsPlus(){
    HiddenWord puzzle = new HiddenWord("AB");
    String hint = puzzle.getHint("BB");

    assertEquals(hint, "+B");
}
```

I got that one to pass, and those 3 tests still only take 0.35 seconds to run. Since I'm confident now that my HiddenWord class is complete I run it against the table that is in your book.

```
@Test
public void TestFromBook(){
    HiddenWord puzzle = new HiddenWord("HARPS");
    assertEquals(puzzle.getHint("AAAAA"), "+A+++");
    assertEquals(puzzle.getHint("HELLO"), "H****");
    assertEquals(puzzle.getHint("HEART"), "H*++*");
    assertEquals(puzzle.getHint("HARMS"), "HAR*S");
    assertEquals(puzzle.getHint("HARPS"), "HARPS");
}
```

and for me, it was no big surprise that the test passed first time with no code changes. And what's more all 4 tests pass in 0.35 seconds.

As for your code itself, java uses pascalCase (Where the first word of a multiword variable is lower case, and each word's first letter after is uppercase) for variable and field names. aword would be aWord.

Since I was so heavy about speaking about time. How would your solution fair if the word to guess was HUGE. I mean.. REALLY REALLY BIG??? Say 1 million characters? As I'm typing this I put your solution under test. I create a 1 million character string, as a hidden word, then use your solution against another 1 million character word. (Its still running).. ok i canceled it after 166 seconds. I then replaced your solution with mine and ran it again. mine finished in about 0.2 seconds. To see your numbers with incremental times it is like this

```
String Length:20000 Time:169.289960 ms 
String Length:40000 Time:481.035566 ms 
String Length:80000 Time:1739.349658 ms
```

exponentially getting bigger. For your purposes this is probably not going to be a problem, but it is something to consider when not only testing, but programming with data in general.

Comment: Thanks! My instructor never covered TestNG, I wish I had known about it sooner.

Comment: Good answer, it'll be even nicer if you can touch upon parameterized testing too! :)

Comment: @h.j.k. I suppose I could have. I assumed that because the O.P. was new that using annotation in the code might be a little bit too deep of a subject. I will edit the answer here shortly to show what the tests could look like if they wanted to look into using parameterized testing.

Answer (score 4):

1. There is an error in your code:

   ```
       if(word.indexOf(buffer) == i)
           result = result + buffer;
   ```

Test it with word="aa" and aguess="aa".

2. your class should really have a single member variable, which is 'word'. The member "length" is not needed since it can be deduced by word, and represents a duplication of information (which, in general, is a bad thing). The variables 'result' and 'buffer' should be local to the function which uses them, since they make no sense outside that function.
3. as already said, you should stick with the names provided in the assignment.

Possible rewriting:

```
public class HiddenWord {
    private String word;

    public HiddenWord(String a_word) {
        word = a_word;
    }

    public String getHint(String a_guess) {
        string result = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (word[i] == a_guess[i])
                result += word[i];
            else if (word.indexOf(a_guess[i]) != -1)
                result += "+";
            else
                result += "*";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: good spotting on th bug.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, common code conventions are useful for communicating your code with others, and for preventing bugs from creeping in later.

In your case, there are two things you have done which are very unconventional. The first is you have a class called with a lower-case name. Java classes should be "CamelCase", and thus, should start with an upper-case letter.

The other item, is you have called it `main`, and that means your class, and its constructor, conflict with the same-named method that is called `main` that Java calls when your class is the entry point.

In essence, `main` is a really, really bad name for your class.

A name like "WordGuesser" would help a lot. Here's your code with that name:

> ```
> public class WordGuesser {
>     private int length;
>     private String word;
>     private String result;
>     private String buffer;
>
>     public WordGuesser(String aword) {
>
>         result = "";
>         word = aword;
>         length = word.length();
>         buffer = "";
>
>     }
>
>     public String guess(String aguess) {
>         for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
>             buffer = aguess.substring(i, i + 1);
>             if (word.indexOf(buffer) == i)
>                 result = result + buffer;
>             else if ((word.indexOf(buffer) != -1))
>                 result = result + "+";
>             if ((word.indexOf(buffer) == -1))
>                 result = result + "*";
>         }
>         return result;
>     }
> }
> ```

I have also added some more conventional spacing. For an experienced Java person to see the above code, it would make much more sense... and be less of a 'jolt' to the system. Suddenly it makes sense.

The next item in there is the cascading if-else-if-if conditions which are unbraced. This is always controversial to criticise, but my experience, and general coding convention, recommends bracing all 1-liners. Your code should be:

> ```
> public String guess(String aguess) {
>     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
>         buffer = aguess.substring(i, i + 1);
>         if (word.indexOf(buffer) == i) {
>             result = result + buffer;
>         } else if ((word.indexOf(buffer) != -1)) {
>             result = result + "+";
>         }
>         if ((word.indexOf(buffer) == -1)) {
>             result = result + "*";
>         }
>     }
>     return result;
> }
> ```

OK, now to point out the other issues I see....

1. your code assumes that the guess will be the same length as the base word. If the guess is shorter, you will get exceptions thrown.
2. `buffer` is stored as an instance field, but it should be declared instead when it is used.... it should be:

   ```
   String buffer = aguess.substring(i, i + 1);
   ```

   (note I added some spaces around the `+` as well).
3. `result` has me really confused... you store it at the class level, and you never 'reset' it. This makes me think you create a new instance of `main` each time you test a `guess`....  otherwise the `result` will just keep getting bigger, and bigger..... I believe that `result` should also just be declared inside the method, and not as a class field....

You should test your code like this:

```
WordGuesser wg = new WordGuesser("Code Review");
System.out.println(wg.guess("oChh hhvhhh");
System.out.println(wg.guess("Cohh xxvxxx");
```

And check the results.....

You will find the output prints more and more each time. A bug.

Comment: In the OP's defense, it looks like the question has defined a guess to have the same length of the hidden word... whether that means OP can safely assume as such, or must *validate* the guess is up to OP to clarify with the teacher. :)

Comment: I agree with your points, but I chose not to upvote this because the requirements in the assignment point to input and output to be all in caps, and that the name of the class to be HiddenWord. Granted WordGuesser is a million times better than main for a class, but the name was given in the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I realized that I have offered three comments on the answers and question, so I'm going to aggregate them here.

1. **Input validation**

   > A guess contains only capital letters and has the same length as the hidden word.

   Does that mean you can safely assume as such, or are you required to validate the input? Sample implementation:

   ```
   public String getHint(String guess) {
       // length being the length of the hidden word
       if (!guess.toUpperCase().equals(guess) || guess.length() != length) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid guess.");
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
2. **Parameterized testing**

   [@Robert Snyder's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/90344/27975) is a good primer to unit testing, and on top of that you can consider doing parameterized testing. In the world of TestNG framework (essentially a continuation of Robert's answer here), that means given your test method argument(s) that TestNG will call with the test inputs you specified:

   ```
   @DataProvider(name="test-cases")
   public Iterator<Object[]> getTestCases() {
       return Arrays.asList(new Object[]{ "AAAAA", "+A+++" },
                           new Object[]{ "HELLO", "H****" },
                           new Object[]{ "HEART", "H*++?" },
                           new Object[]{ "HARMS", "HAR*S" },
                           new Object[]{ "HARPS", "HARPS" }).iterator();
   }

   // note that TestNG will interpret the two-element
   // Object[] array as the two arguments below
   @Test(data-provider="test-cases")
   public void doTest(String guess, String expected) {
       assertEquals(puzzle.getHint(guess), expected);
   }
   ```

   The main benefit of this is that each test input is treated as a standalone test case, so a failure will not prevent other cases from running. In my example above, I have intentionally changed the expected value for `"HEART"` to contain an invalid `?` character, so running this test will tell me that 4/5 cases have passed, with the failure on `"HEART"`.
3. **Possible bug in the question**

   There's a possible *bug in the question*: Why will guessing `AAAAA` for `HARPS` result in 4 `+`, since the only `A` has been guessed correctly? Using another example, given a guess `BBA` for the word `ABA`, I will expect the output to be `*BA`, since there is no extra `B` and only the last `A` has been matched in the right position.

   The question may not call for it, but I think a prudent solution should also eliminate matching characters first before checking whether the remaining ones are in the wrong positions or not.

Comment: I too wondered your point # 3. My guess is that the teacher didn't want to make it super hard to check if the character has already been found and placed, but instead just allow them to use the "contains" method. IMO this would make the overall solution much easier on beginners.